# Why does my traded Pokemon have an encounter date in the future?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I had a look at my Gyarados's summary I just got him from trade and when I had a look at where he was from, it said a faraway place (I know what that means) and the date was 2018 (I was surprised about the year and I don't know the rest of the date) how is he from 2018? It's 2017 and time machines don't exist...

How is he from/ meet in 2018? It's really weird, is it a glitch or something?

Comment: It's an hacked Pokemon, that's why it has a future encounter date.

Comment: OMG :( ok I am releaseing it but is the mega stone it has hacked or can I keep it?  :0

Comment: Safe to say the Mega Stone is also hacked in and not a legit obtained one.  Or at the very least cloned from a real one.

Answer (score 4):

It likely means it was hacked into the game.

From a Faraway place is always related to event Pokemon, and the only event Gyarados were given away in Japan and South Korea, between 2014-2016.

Suffice to say, you have a hacked Pokemon. It will have no effect on your game or you unless you try to compete in an official tournament.

Comment: Is his mega stone still ok to keep?

Comment: @Help That should be okay. It was likely hacked, but it's virtually impossible to prove.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to @SGR's answer, the encounter date uses the 3DS's own date and time. If your 3DS's clock is set to say 2018, catching a pokemon will also say it was caught in 2018, even when you set the clock back to 2017.